# What can cause this error: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE, Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PowerShell.SyncPackage

Tags: powershell, iis-7, msdeploy, webdeploy

Using a Powershell scripted web deploy job, I am receiving this error on some hosts:

```
C:\> Get-Service msdepsvc,wmsvc
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  msdepsvc           Web Deployment Agent Service
Running  wmsvc              Web Management Service

C:\> (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server' -Name EnableRemoteManagement).EnableRemoteManagement
1

C:\> Add-PSSnapin WDeploySnapin3.0
C:\> $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("some-domain\some-user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force))
C:\> New-WDPublishSettings -ComputerName localhost -Credentials $credential -AllowUntrusted -Site "Default Web Site" -SiteUrl "http://localhost" -AgentType WMSvc -FileName publish.xml

AllowUntrusted          : True
PublishUrl              : localhost
SiteName                : Default Web Site
SiteUrl                 : http://localhost
Username                : some-domain\some-user
Password                : password
MySqlDBConnectionString :
SqlDBConnectionString   :
AgentType               : WMSvc
UseNTLM                 : False
OtherAttributes         : {}

C:\> Restore-WDPackage "package.zip" -DestinationPublishSettings publish.xml
Restore-WDPackage : Could not connect to the remote computer ("localhost"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web
Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-WDPackage "package.zip" -DestinationPublishSett ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Restore-WDPackage], DeploymentDetailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE,Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PowerShell.SyncPackage
```

The Windows firewall is not running and the same script runs successfully on other machines (the package is successfully deployed, the website works as expected). As shown above, msdepsvc and wmsvc are both running and wmsvc is configured to allow remote connections. The same machine that fails to accept the Restore-WDPackage command, does accept remote management connections from the IIS management console (after running `Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server' -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1` and restarting the service). The [MS help link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE) contains no clues and [the documentation for WDeploySnapin3.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets) is not really complete. Other WinRM commands work fine (we create the target website with [this](https://gist.github.com/grenade/8057291) script).

What else could be causing the error?

Comment: Maybe increasing logging will help, although if its not reaching the server it may not add any value.  Worth a shot though - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461173(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Try using WebDeploy directly, do you get the same error? I've seen this error when the agent is not running in the box, or the machine is referenced by IP rather then host. Try using computerName rather than localhost.